# Need to multiply only certain cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Here is a screenshot of my spreadsheet:

[image]

I am trying to format the "Annual Cost" cell where it will show: Frequency Per Year * The cell that has a value between Linear Feet / Square Feet / Acre * the corresponding per $ amount.

I have searched answered questions and I have whittled it down to using =IF(ISBLANK) but I can't figure out how to format it.

Thanks for any help and I can tip btc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you opposed to using a nested IF?  If not I would suggest

```
=IF(D2, C2*D2*E2, IF(F2, C2*F2*G2, IF(H2, C2*H2*I2, " ")))
```

I realize you asked about using ISBLANK and you could use it a similar way here if you were to switch around my Then/Else statements but I think it becomes more complicated that way

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2), IF(ISBLANK(F2), IF(ISBLANK(H2), " ", C2*H2*I2), C2*F2*G2), C2*D2*E2)
```

Comment: I am not opposed to using a nested IF. I have copied your formula into my spreadsheet and it has returned a "-". Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was trying to read your rows from the small picture inserted above.  Is E or F the column for Linear Feet?  I am assuming the cost columns are numbers formatted as currency or accounting to display the $ sign and aren't text with the $ in the cell itself, is that accurate?

Comment: Linear Feet is in column D.

Comment: Ah okay, let me edit this formula really quickly then. How about now?

Comment: =IF(D2, C2*D2*E2, IF(F2, C2*F2*G2, IF(H2, C2*H2*I2, " "))) This works perfectly! Thanks so much for your help. Post your BTC wallet and I'll tip you. I can see how the formula works and will keep this technique in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: No tip necessary.  I'd appreciate accepting the answer though.  Oh and I threw that empty quote on the end so you can fill in as many rows as you want and nothing will show in the cell until at least one of the cells has a value in it (no annoying error message)

Comment: I see. I was wondering what those quotes did. I hope to one day be an excel pro like yourself. I will answer the question now, trying to figure out how to do that...I have clicked the check and it is green.